# Why isn't my principled volume registering texture inputs - Eevee

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics, osx

So I have been wanting to add animated ground fog to my scene in eevee in Blender 3.0, however I have come across this issue where any texture I add to my Principled volume's density input or emission strength input doesn't register the texture. When I go to render the scene is completely missing the volume all together as well. This was also an issue for me in 2.9 as well as 2.8. I have yet to find a good article or video explaining the problem or any kind of solution.

This is without the texture plugged in
[image]

And here is what happens when I plug in any kind of texture
[image]

I am running Blender 3.0 on a 2019 MacBook Pro with a 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7 CPU and a AMD Radeon Pro 5300M 4 GB GPU. I have a feeling this might be a Mac issue more than anything else, but if anyone has a solution I would highly appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

Reading up on it, unfortunately, your exact problem has been a bug since Feb 2019. There have been hacky solutions however. Try replacing the Texture Coordinate node with a Geometry node. Sorry I cannot confirm since I do not own a macOS device.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the input ! I had a feeling that was the case, I'll try that geometry node trick and come back to see if we have any success !